# Twenty Fifteen - Page.php not called - always 404s

Tags: theme-twenty-fifteen

This is a fresh install of WordPress 4.1.1 on a WIMP stack. Theme used is the stock OOBE "Twenty Fifteen" theme, NO plugins enabled as of now.

Issue:
I have a WP site that has both PAGES and POSTS. The Permalink structure is set to:

`Custom: /%category%/%postname%`

The posts work perfectly fine. I have two static pages: one is an About Me page and the other a Contact page (that provides contact info). When I navigate to either of the two static pages, the `404.php` is executed instead of `page.php`.

Switching the permalink structure to anything else except the first default setting (http://[blogurl]/?p=[id]) doesnt help :-(

Funny thing is, I have the exact same build of WP (folder copy from downloaded master ZIP file) that has only Pages. Here, all pages work fine (same 2015 theme).

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion - make sure that the permalink that you are navigating to is exactly the one you want. If you have trashed a 'first version' of the About page and started over using the same page title the permalink will not be 'about' it will be something like 'about-2'

Placing the first version in the trash folder does not delete it, it just makes it inaccessible. You can always restore it if you want. It does not get removed from the database until you 'empty trash.' Since it is still in the database, WordPress needs some way to differentiate between the two pages - so it adds a number to the second version of a page with a title identical to one already in the database.

The page/post ID is unique, so using that type permalink would work, but if you are using the page/post name then the trashed version will return a 404.

I hope the problem is this simple.

Comment: That's a good gotcha that I have faced before. Now I ensure I empty trash as soon as I delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by setting:

Custom Structure: `/%pagename%`

(for some reason, for WP 4.1.1, `%pagename%` finds posts, but `%postname%` does not find pages!)

Category base & Tag name : (clear)

I had this set to `%category%` and `%tag%` earlier.